# Fastest way to map a dict on a df (multiple columns)

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have the following data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({0: {0: 'EFG',
  1: 'EFG',
  2: 'EFG',
  3: 'EFG',
  4: 'EFG',
  5: 'EFG',
  6: 'EFG',
  7: 'ABC',
  8: 'EFG',
  9: 'EFG',
  10: 'EFG',
  11: 'EFG',
  12: 'EFG',
  13: 'EFG',
  14: 'EFG',
  15: 'EFG',
  16: 'EFG',
  17: 'EFG',
  18: 'EFG',
  19: 'EFG',
  20: 'ABC',
  21: 'EFG',
  22: 'EFG',
  23: 'EFG',
  24: 'EFG',
  25: 'EFG',
  26: 'EFG',
  27: 'EFG',
  28: 'EFG',
  29: 'EFG'},
 1: {0: 'DS',
  1: 'DS',
  2: 'DS',
  3: 'Q',
  4: 'DS',
  5: 'DS',
  6: 'DS',
  7: 'DS',
  8: 'DS',
  9: 'DS',
  10: 'DS',
  11: 'DS',
  12: 'DS',
  13: 'DS',
  14: 'DS',
  15: 'DS',
  16: 'DS',
  17: 'DS',
  18: 'DS',
  19: 'DS',
  20: 'DS',
  21: 'DS',
  22: 'DAS',
  23: 'DAS',
  24: 'DAS',
  25: 'DS',
  26: 'DS',
  27: 'Q',
  28: 'DS',
  29: 'DS'},
 2: {0: '321',
  1: '900',
  2: '900',
  3: '900',
  4: '1000',
  5: '1000',
  6: '1000',
  7: '444',
  8: '900',
  9: '900',
  10: '321',
  11: '900',
  12: '1000',
  13: '900',
  14: '321',
  15: '321',
  16: '1000',
  17: '1000',
  18: '1000',
  19: '1000',
  20: '444',
  21: '900',
  22: '12345',
  23: '12345',
  24: '321',
  25: '321',
  26: '12345',
  27: '1000',
  28: '900',
  29: '321'}})
```

and the following dict:

```
{('ABC', 'AS', '1000'): 123,
 ('ABC', 'AS', '444'): 321,
 ('ABC', 'AS', '231341'): 421,
 ('ABC', 'AS', '888'): 412,
 ('ABC', 'AS', '087'): 4215,
 ('ABC', 'DAS', '1000'): 3415,
 ('ABC', 'DAS', '444'): 4215,
 ('ABC', 'DAS', '231341'): 3214,
 ('ABC', 'DAS', '888'): 321,
 ('ABC', 'DAS', '087'): 111,
 ('ABC', 'Q', '1000'): 222,
 ('ABC', 'Q', '444'): 3214,
 ('ABC', 'Q', '231341'): 421,
 ('ABC', 'Q', '888'): 321,
 ('ABC', 'Q', '087'): 41,
 ('ABC', 'DS', '1000'): 421,
 ('ABC', 'DS', '444'): 421,
 ('ABC', 'DS', '231341'): 321,
 ('ABC', 'DS', '888'): 41,
 ('ABC', 'DS', '087'): 41,
 ('EFG', 'AS', '1000'): 213,
 ('EFG', 'AS', '900'): 32,
 ('EFG', 'AS', '12345'): 1,
 ('EFG', 'AS', '321'): 3,
 ('EFG', 'DAS', '1000'): 421,
 ('EFG', 'DAS', '900'): 321,
 ('EFG', 'DAS', '12345'): 123,
 ('EFG', 'DAS', '321'): 31,
 ('EFG', 'Q', '1000'): 41,
 ('EFG', 'Q', '900'): 51,
 ('EFG', 'Q', '12345'): 321,
 ('EFG', 'Q', '321'): 321,
 ('EFG', 'DS', '1000'): 41,
 ('EFG', 'DS', '900'): 51,
 ('EFG', 'DS', '12345'): 321,
 ('EFG', 'DS', '321'): 1}
```

This is of course only a sample of my df, and I have multiple dicts like this one.
I am looking for the fastest way to map this dict to this dataframe, based on the 3 columns. I need to run this multiple times during ,y analysis, so I am looking for the optimal solution in term of running time.

what i tried already:

```
def map_d(a,b,c):
    return d1[(a,b,c)]
res = [map_d(*a) for a in tuple(zip(df[0], df[1], df[2]))]
23.1 µs ± 335 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

performance on real data:
    170 ms ± 5.47 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)



res = df.apply(lambda x: d1[(x[0],x[1],x[2])],axis=1)
742 µs ± 16.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
performance on real data:
    7.27 s ± 201 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

I am looking for fastest solutions (I can build the dict differently if needed)
Thanks

Comment: I wouldn't call it rude, I am struggling with this one for some time, but I just added what I did so far. Thanks for the feedback

Comment: Do you need working with 100, 1k or 10M or more rows DataFrames?

Comment: 300K, but to run this with 4 different dictionaries, 6 times. So 24 times

Comment: @David - Ok, is possible test each solution with your real data and add it to question? thanks.

Comment: @jezreal I just added them, Thanks :)

Comment: @Neither, I agree with the feedback, just not with the language and the "rude" :) but really thanks for that

Comment: @David - I think with solutions from answers. ;)

Comment: @jezrael just added them. The last one you suggested is pretty good. I wonder if there is something better

Comment: @David - one idea - `[d[(a,b,c)] for a,b,c in df[[0,1,2]].to_numpy()]`

Comment: @ jezrael  added the performance of this.. the previous one is better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For improve performance in larger DataFrames is possible use `Series` with [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
```

---

```
df1 = df.join(pd.Series(d, name='new'), on=[0,1,2])
print (df1.head(10))
     0   1     2  new
0  EFG  DS   321    1
1  EFG  DS   900   51
2  EFG  DS   900   51
3  EFG   Q   900   51
4  EFG  DS  1000   41
5  EFG  DS  1000   41
6  EFG  DS  1000   41
7  ABC  DS   444  421
8  EFG  DS   900   51
9  EFG  DS   900   51
```

Another idea (similar solution like in question):

```
 res = [d[(a,b,c)] for a,b,c in zip(df[0], df[1], df[2])]
```

Or:

```
 res = [d[(a,b,c)] for a,b,c in df[[0,1,2]].to_numpy()]
```

Comment: The second one gives 43.4 ms ± 8.12 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each) on real data

Comment: @David - Super, from 170ms to `43ms` ? Very nice.

Comment: The numpy one is 159 ms ± 4.72 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

Answer (score -1):

Convert your dataframe as `MultiIndex` and extract values from your dict (`Series`):

```
out = pd.Series(d).loc[pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(df)] \
        .rename('values').reset_index()
```

Output:

```
>>> out
      0    1      2  values
0   EFG   DS    321       1
1   EFG   DS    900      51
2   EFG   DS    900      51
3   EFG    Q    900      51
4   EFG   DS   1000      41
5   EFG   DS   1000      41
6   EFG   DS   1000      41
7   ABC   DS    444     421
8   EFG   DS    900      51
9   EFG   DS    900      51
10  EFG   DS    321       1
11  EFG   DS    900      51
12  EFG   DS   1000      41
13  EFG   DS    900      51
14  EFG   DS    321       1
15  EFG   DS    321       1
16  EFG   DS   1000      41
17  EFG   DS   1000      41
18  EFG   DS   1000      41
19  EFG   DS   1000      41
20  ABC   DS    444     421
21  EFG   DS    900      51
22  EFG  DAS  12345     123
23  EFG  DAS  12345     123
24  EFG  DAS    321      31
25  EFG   DS    321       1
26  EFG   DS  12345     321
27  EFG    Q   1000      41
28  EFG   DS    900      51
29  EFG   DS    321       1
```

Comment: cant test it on real data due to pandas version, but on sample data, these are the performaces: 4.89 ms ± 393 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
not an improvement from what i shared